# Getting the Cell Address of Checkbox when ticked

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, vba7

Hy, I am working on Excel VBA which will get me the Cell Address of the Checkbox I tick at the moment. I am able to get the cell address using following code.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes
          Debug.Print chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 0).Address
Next chk

End Sub
```

This code returns the Cell address of all Check-boxes but I only want one cell address of the checkbox I tick. How can I achieve this. 
 Currently I am trying events to achieve this but have no success so far.

Comment: I think this would probably be solved by enabling click event on check-boxes but I can't find how can I enable click event on all check-boxes

Comment: @Warcupine How can I add **_change** event to all check-boxes as I don't have names for all check-boxes and number of check-boxes may change.

Comment: It looks that your check boxes are of the type sheet Form. Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what type of checkbox you have or how they are created but you can set a command with ```.onaction```

Comment: Yes, I have sheet form check boxes. I created them from Developer -> Insert -> Form Control -> Check box

Comment: Assign the same macro to all the checkboxes, then within that macro you can use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the clicked-on checkbox.  From there you can use something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes(checkBoxName).TopLeftCell`   Note that this relies on your checkboxes being positioned accurately and not overlapping any other cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams ok I find this solution interesting, let me study Application.caller and try it. But it has one fault that I have to assign the macro to all check-boxes. We may also have new check-boxes in future, Is there a workaround using click event on all check-boxes.

Comment: Check my answer code, please. It will assign a single macro to all your existing check boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the next way, please:

1. Copy the next Sub in a standard module:

```
Sub GetChkBoxAddress()
  MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code, too, and run it:

```
Sub textAssignMacroChkBox()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, chkB As CheckBox
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  For Each s In sh.Shapes
     If TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        s.OnAction = "GetChkBoxAddress"
     End If
  Next
End Sub
```

3. Try checking and unchecking the check boxes...

If you need to return the cell address only when the check box is checked (not for unchecking) the code can be adapted...

**Edited:**

In order to retrieve the cell address only for checking, you can use the next adapted `Sub`:

```
Sub GetChkBoxAddress()
 If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a great solution but not perfect for current situation, What if I had to add new check boxes in future ?

Comment: @abdulsamad: You will simple run `textAssignMacroChkBox` again and it will assign the same macro to all existing ones... Isn't it convenient?

Comment: yeah some what I will add it in Workbook_Open event so that it automatically adds macro to all check-boxes. But perfect solution would something like using **checkbox click event which runs the same code**.

Comment: @abdulsamad: I am afraid you did not understand anything from my code. **This is what it does**! It assigns **the same macro, able to identify the clicked check box** for all existing check boxes in the sheet... You can use the Workbook_Open event, but you must run the code **if you add new check boxes**, as you said.

Comment: I have understood everything from your code, but I didn't wanted to run the same code over and over again each time I create new check-box that's why I was trying to find the perfect solution of using click event.

Comment: I think I can go with your code for now and thanks for it :)

Comment: @abdulsamad: Then, do not run it! Pray to God or Alag to make a miracle... How do you imagine that such a check box will be born with such a macro allocation by itself?

Comment: @abdulsamad: Should I understand that my code did not answer your question? If so, can you clearly specify which are your expectations? I mean, how would you like to have this macro allocation to the new added check boxes?

Comment: No I didn't mean that.  Your solution is very good and would do my work for now. I was only emphasising a minor problem it could have in future while adding new check-boxes.

Comment: @abdulsamad: If you do not like the automate assignation, you can simple execute a right click on the newly created check box, choose 'Assing Macro...' and assign the macro `GetChkBoxAddress`... Does this solution look being more convenient for you?

Comment: @abdulsamad: When a a piece of code, or a solution answers our question, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **Accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works. Our purpose here is not to write macros for somebody needed it. We should make people learn as much as possible...